# Alerting selected option appears repeatedly

Tags: jquery

The `alert` works first time. However when I change the `option` again (without refreshing the page) then it alerts both options, ie. the first selected option and the second selected option too.

I want to get value of only the selected option when I click on the button. Can anyone guide me on how I can achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.button').click(function() {
      alert(value);
    });
  });
  $(".test").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.button2').click(function() {
      alert(value);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<select class="test">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button class="button" value="button">button</button>
<button class="button2" value="button2">button2</button>
```

You can test my code by placing in below url

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_change_ref

Comment: The problem is because you're creating a new `click` handler *every time the `change` event fires*. Move the `click` handler **outside** of the `change`.

Comment: Click event triggered inside your change event , its a infinite loop ! ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var value;
  $(".test").change(function(){
    value = $(this).val();
  });
  $('.button').click(function(){
      alert(value);
  });
});
</script>

<select class="test">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button class="button" value="button">button</button>
```

As suggested by @Rory

Comment: Yes i dint :P my bad,

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the click handler immediately, and only once, not on every change of the input, since then you *accumulate* all those click handlers... resulting in an increasing amount of alerts:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value; // scope of variable must include both handlers
    $(".test").change(function(){
        value = $(this).val();
    }).change(); // let it execute also immediately
    $('.button').click(function(){
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="test">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button class="button" value="button">button</button>
```

Of course, one could just do `alert($(".test").val())` and forget about the `change` handler completely, and just keep the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Use .off() , method removes event handlers that were attached with .on().

```
$(document).off().on('click', '.button', function() {
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    //$('.button').click(function() {
    $(document).off().on('click', '.button, .button2', function() {
      alert(value);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="test">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button class="button" value="button">button</button>
<button class="button2" value="button2">button2</button>
```

Comment: I mean, technically this would work, but it's very far from being good practice.

Comment: Ahh thanks. Learn new things. Keep this tip on mind.

Comment: @Shree I can not use off()  for two times  as last off() will only works any suggestion
as i have two different button and one select option

Answer (score 0):

> try this:

```
var value = '';
  $(document).ready(function(){

  });

  $(document).on('change', '.test', function(){
      value = $(this).val();
    });

   $(document).on('click', '.button', function(){
      alert(value);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".test").change(function() {
       alert($(this).find(":selected").val())
    })
})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Next time I will try to explain